# How to change landing page other than default.aspx?

Tags: asp.net, iis

We have an internal ticketing tool which is written in ASP.NET 2.0. The `default.aspx` is the only one web page which contains all the code.

I want to introduce a landing page which provides more information to users before they start entering support ticket.

I don't want to touch the default.aspx as it is there for ages. so renaming etc will lead to lots of testing.

The webaddress looks like this `http://server/ticketing` and land to default.aspx.

Can I somehow make to land on different page and from there I want to divert users (via clicking a link) may be to the default.aspx.

Can I use IIS to do this trick?

Comment: WebForms or MVC?

Comment: For WebForms you could `inetgmr.exe > Sites > Your Site > Your App > Default Document`. For MVC just change the routing.

Comment: Webforms. Some 7-8 years old cdoe